# How to highlight a citation

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, highlighting

I need to highlight a citation of a publication list (required for a grant application). I tried to use `\hl` but got the following error message:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation '{abc}' on page 0 undefined on input line 25.

! Argument of \blx@citeargs@iii has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.25    \item \hl{\fullcite{abc}}
```

Here is the code (no error if commenting out the 3rd last line `\item \hl{\fullcite{abc}}`)

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}
\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=0mm}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber,maxbibnames=99,defernumbers=true,sorting=ynt,giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{abc,
author = {John Doe and Jane Doe and Kate Smith and Bob Muller},
year = {1970},
title = {Article Title which is indeed very long},
journaltitle = {Journal Name which is indeed also very very very very long},
volume = {1},
number = {2},
pages = {13--17},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\section{Publications}
 \begin{enumerate}
   \item \fullcite{abc}
   %\item \hl{\fullcite{abc}}
 \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

I tried to use `colorbox` as suggested but this forces the citation to be on one single line and therefore the citation goes out of the margins of the document:

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color} 
\usepackage{soul}
\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=0mm}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber,maxbibnames=99,defernumbers=true,sorting=ynt,giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{abc,
author = {John Doe and Jane Doe and Kate Smith and Bob Muller},
year = {1970},
title = {Article Title which is indeed very long},
journaltitle = {Journal Name which is indeed also very very very very long},
volume = {1},
number = {2},
pages = {13--17},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\section{Publications}
 \begin{enumerate}
   \item \fullcite{abc}
   \item \colorbox{BurntOrange}{\fullcite{abc}}
 \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your example is way too long. Show only the really relevant code. Beside this: if the cite goes over more than one line it won't work. If you can use lualatex you could use lua-ul. With pdflatex use a colorbox or e.g. tikz to add a background.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I shortened the code and added a screenshot of the .pdf

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I tried to use `colorbox` as you suggested but this forces the citation to be on one single line and therefore the citation goes out of the margins of the document. I edited the question with code and output. Do you have another idea/suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `\parbox` nested in a `\colorbox` is enough:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[style=authoryear ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\section{Publications}
 \begin{enumerate}
    \item \fullcite{abc}
    \item \colorbox{yellow}{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\fullcite{abc}}}
 \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: Great @Fran! Many thanks!